# Incrementing iTunes Connect version number from a version that never shipped

Tags: app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I have an app in iTunes Connect, that I have been TestFlight beta testing. It's labelled as version 0.1. I'm now ready to submit to the App Store, but I'd like it to ship as version 1.0. However I can't see anywhere to create a new version.

Am I missing something? Or will I need to submit as 0.1 and then increment to 1.0 in my next update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In iTunesConnect go to *My Apps* –> *[Your app]*
2. Scroll down to *General App Information*
3. Under Version Number, change it.

As simple as that.
Hope it helps :)